# Apache server configuration for Whisper OpenAI

Tags: apache, ssl, openai-whisper

Good afternoon,
I have installed Whisper from OpenAI on a Linux server with Ubuntu and Apache as web server. I followed the tutorial in the README.md file hosted in https://huggingface.co/spaces/aadnk/whisper-webui using python.

When I access via HTTP without SSL to http://whisper.mydomain.com:7860/ it works perfectly.

[image: HTTP]

But when I access via HTTPS with SSL to https://whisper.mydomain.com/ redirecting the traffic to port 7860 with Apache, the web interface loads, but when I upload the same file to transcribe the audio, it keeps loading and never shows me the results.

[image: HTTPS]

Here is my Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName whisper.mydomain.com
Redirect / https://whisper.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName whisper.mydomain.com
ProxyPass / http://whisper.mydomain.com:7860/
ProxyPassReverse / http://whisper.mydomain.com:7860/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/AlphaSSL__.mydomain.com.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/AlphaSSL__.mydomain.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea what I can do to make it work properly? Thanks..

Comment: I removed the single "Whisper" tag, as that tag has to to with Graphite and backend storage, not OpenAI -- The current `openai-whisper` tag is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning, I solved my problem by uninstalling Apache and using Nginx instead, with the following configuration file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name whisper.mydomain.com;
return 301 https://whisper.mydomain.com/;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name whisper.mydomain.com;

ssl_certificate "/etc/ssl/certs/AlphaSSL__.mydomain.com.pem";
ssl_certificate_key "/etc/ssl/private/AlphaSSL__.mydomain.com.key";

location / {
    proxy_pass http://whisper.mydomain.com:7860;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}

}
```